# How to create a 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

When creating a 2D array. I am getting an error "warning excess element in scalar initializer".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    int arr = {{'00','01','02'},{'10','11','12'},{'20','21','22'},{'30','31','32'}};

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<4;j++){
            printf('%s', arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And you really should pay more attention in class, or read a book. What is e.g. `'12'` supposed to be? How can you initialize a single `int` variable with an array of anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to write strings of characters in C source code is with quotation marks (`"`), not apostrophes (`'`). Apostrophes are for single characters (or, in rare circumstances, a few characters combined to make a single integer). Thus your `printf` should be:

```
printf("%s", arr[i][j]);
```

It appears you want your array to hold either strings of characters or pointers to (the first characters of) strings. For the latter, you should declare your array with `char *`, not `int`.

To declare an array, you must use brackets (`[` and `]`) to give it dimensions. It is not sufficient merely to list multiple values for it. So your declaration should be:

```
char *arr[4][3] = {{"00","01","02"},{"10","11","12"},{"20","21","22"},{"30","31","32"}};
```

For the first dimension, the brackets are still required but you may omit the number to let the compiler derive it by counting the initializers:

```
char *arr[][3] = {{"00","01","02"},{"10","11","12"},{"20","21","22"},{"30","31","32"}};
```

The subscripts you use with an array must match its dimensions. You listed only three initializers for each row of the array, so it seems to have three elements in that dimension, but your loop uses four:

```
for(int j = 0;j<4;j++){
```

Either that `4` should be changed to `3`, or you should declare the array as `char *arr[4][4]` and provide one more element for each row.